# Adding Custom Dialog box in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I am having issue to add a custom dialog box in react.js

```
  loginUser = async (user) => {
// add user to backend
try {
  // const {
  //   email,
  //   password,
  // } = this.state;
  // const res = await Axios({
  //   url: "/api/auth/signin",
  //   method: "POST",
  //   data: {
  //     email,
  //     password,
  //   },
  // });
  alert("LoggedIN...");
} catch (error) {
  alert(`Something went wrong! \n ${error.response.data.msg}`);
}};
```

This is the code with the default alert box above--

```
     loginUser = async (user) => {
    // add user to backend
    try {
   const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`Something went wrong! \n ${error.response.data.msg}`);
    }
  };
```

This will after adding the custom dialog box, but ti says ** React Hook "React.useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks**

The whole code is given below--

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Input, /*WithPasswordStrength*/ } from "../../components/Input/index.js";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
//import Axios from "axios";

import style from './login.module.scss'

const womenImg = require("../../images/women.png").default;

export class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    errors: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
    },
  };

  registerHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      errors: { email: "", password: "" },
    }));
    // validation
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    // email
    const emailTest = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
    if (!emailTest.test(email)) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        errors: { ...prevState.errors, email: "Email is not valid." },
      }));
      return;
    }

    // password
    if (!password) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        errors: { ...prevState.errors, password: "Password cannot be empty" },
      }));
      return;
    }
    if (password.length < 6) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        errors: {
          ...prevState.errors,
          password: "Password length must be atleast 6 characters.",
        },
      }));
      return;
    }
    this.loginUser();
  };

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  loginUser = async (user) => {
    // add user to backend
    try {
   const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open alert dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      >
        <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{"Use Google's location service?"}</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
            Let Google help apps determine location. This means sending anonymous location data to
            Google, even when no apps are running.
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
            Disagree
          </Button>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
            Agree
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`Something went wrong! \n ${error.response.data.msg}`);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <div className={style["login-page"]}>
          <div className="grid-container">
            <div className="grid-x align-middle">
              <div className="cell large-4 medium-4">
                <h2 className={style["login-page__title"]}>Login</h2>
                <form
                  onSubmit={this.registerHandler}
                  className={style["login-page__form"]}
                >
                  <Input
                    label="Email Address"
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="username@example.com"
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    error={errors.email}
                  />
                  <Input
                    label="Create Password"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="************"
                    name="password"
                    onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    error={errors.password}
                  />
                  <button className={style["button__big"]}>Login</button>
                </form>
                <Link>
                  Don't have an account?{" "}
                  <span style={{ color: "#2F80ED" }}><Link to="/register">Register here</Link></span>.
                </Link>
              </div>
              <div className="cell large-8">
                  <div className={style["registration-page__illustration-wrapper"]}>
                  <img src={womenImg} className="registration-page__illustration" alt="Illustration of women"/>
                </div>
              </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. useState is a hook, you cannot use it in a class component. 2. You cannot use it in an event handler: loginUser. It should be called at the top level of your function component

Answer (score 0):

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

It can be see that exception handler works well